# How is it possible to access homepage from package.json in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created a react app that will be served from `/example-path`. I defined it in the `package.json` like this:

```json
"homepage":"/example-path"
```

It has worked so far, but now I would like to add routing with `react-router-dom`, and it incorrectly detects `/example-path` as the part of the URL.

This is my code:

```html
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/product/:id" children={<DisplayProduct />} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Unfortunately `react-router-dom` tries to match the full URL `/example-path/product/10`. How is it possible to avoid that? Is it possible to access the `homepage` variable somehow?

---

I could use `<Router basename="/example-path">`, but in that way, this parameter is a duplicate. I would like to define it in only one place.

Comment: you don't need to access Package.json to read which is your homepage route. You want to add a concern to Package.json that does not belong to it. You can use a config.js with this configurable args and read it wherever you like.

Comment: @JoelBonetR In a react project, the project root path has do be defined in the homepage parameter of package.json. That's not my choise

Comment: hmm no, why you should add the project root path in the package.json?
You only have the entry point of your app in your package.json if you had set scripts to simplify the running, such "parcel index.js" or similar

Comment: @JoelBonetR Otherwise if I put my app to `/example-path/...` the app tries to load assets from `/static/` instead of `/example-path/static/...`

Comment: so you linked/required resources on a bad manner and now you want to add the full path instead...
example-path must be the root path of your application, so when you link an asset you must use relative path './static/asset'. *Note the dot before the slash

Comment: @JoelBonetR No, I created the app with `npx create-react-app`. I did not add additional assets to it

Comment: can you provide a pic of your project's structure and the package.json code?

Comment: Do you have access to your bundler config ? (webpack, ...)

Answer (score 7):

### How is it possible to access homepage from package.json in a react app?

> *We can access the URL set in package.json's `homepage` field using **`PUBLIC_URL`** environment variable.*

We sometimes use a relative URL to deploy the application in subdirectories for example we are deploying the application in `https://myhostname.com/example-path`.

In order to do that, we can either set the environment variable `PUBLIC_URL=/example-path` for the application build or set the package.json homepage attribute to `"/example-path"`. In your case, you have set the

```
"homepage": '/example-path/'
```

then the `PUBLIC_URL` would be set to `/example-path/`. Now you can access this environment variable anywhere in your react application.

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/product/:id" children={<DisplayProduct />} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

After running the `npm run build`, you can check in the `build/index.html` that all the places where you used the `%PUBLIC_URL%` is set to `/example-path/` like below;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/example-path/static/js/main.ec7f1972.js">
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Router` doesn't know anything about your `package.json`. It just looks at the browser location. You can set a [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) if you use `BrowserRouter`:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router';
```

```
<Router basename="/example-path">
    {/* ... */}
</Router>
```

Comment: @IterAtor The `package.json` is not meant to be read by your app code, but by a package manager. You could maybe build a tool that reads it and makes it available as built-time variables in your javascript modules but why all that efford? I don't know of any available tool that does this. But you would still have to provide that as a `basename` to the `Router`. As the `basename` will likely not change often, this is pretty much wasted time.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** With the addition of environment variables to `react-scripts@0.2.3` and higher prefer [@Alan Omars answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582882/3083470): Prefix an environment variable with `REACT_APP_` and it will be exposed to the client at build time. [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

**Here's the old answer that uses the fact that Webpack blindly replaces `%PUBLIC_URL%`in `index.html`:**

Assuming you are using `create-react-app`, this is actually pretty straightforward:

Add the following to `public/index.html`:

```
<script>
  window.PUBLIC_URL = "%PUBLIC_URL%";
</script>
```

now you can reference the homepage from JavaScript! Simply access it via

```
const myPublicUrl = window.PUBLIC_URL;
```

Note: The variable will be an empty string if no `homePage` field is set in the `package.json`, so we have to compensate for that:

```
<Router basename={window.PUBLIC_URL && window.PUBLIC_URL.length > 0 ? window.PUBLIC_URL : "/"}>
    {/* ... */}
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `create-react-app` package you can use [environment variable](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) instead of `"homepage":"/example-path"` in your `package.json`:

1. create `.env` file in the root of your project.
2. add `REACT_APP_HOME_PAGE='/example-path/'` to the `.env` file
3. now you can access your env variable through
   `process.env.REACT_APP_HOME_PAGE` in your app like the following:

   ```
   <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_HOME_PAGE}>
   ```

Comment: This doesn't work for built app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is the location of your Router file but you can try to import it as json in `src/index.js` file that created by `create-react-app` cli app like below;

```js
import myPackageJson from '../package.json';
```

or

```js
import { homepage } from '../package.json';
```

Comment: This doesn't work for compiled app.